# Unión de variables con NA en un mismo data frame en rstudio

Tags: r, rstudio

necesito combinar 3 variables en solo 1, reemplazando los NA por los valores disponibles. Por ejemplo:

```
|var1 | var1.x|var1.y 
------------------------
|NA   | 60    |  NA   |  
|1    | NA    |  NA   |
|7    | NA    |  NA   |
|NA   | NA    |  66   |
|NA   | 10    |  NA   |
```

Pero necesito dejar solo una variable que combine todos los datos disponibles, para que quede así:

```
var1
-----
60
1  
7
66
10
```

Comment: ¿Y que pasa si tienes dos columnas con valores?¿cual de las dos elijes?

Comment: Todas las columnas tienen un solo valor disponible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

La siguiente respuesta no considera el caso donde hay mas de un  valor en una misma fila, pero funciona para la muestra de datos que compartes.

```
#Leemos los datos
df<-read.table(text= 'var1 var1.x var1.y
NA 60 NA     
1 NA NA   
7 NA NA   
NA NA 66   
NA 10 NA',header=T)

# Pegamos por filas solo los valores distintos de NA.
df$new_var<-apply(df,1,FUN=function(x){
    as.numeric(paste0(x[!is.na(x)],collapse=""))
})

df

  var1 var1.x var1.y new_var
1    NA      60     NA      60
2     1      NA     NA       1
3     7      NA     NA       7
4    NA      NA     66      66
5    NA      10     NA      10
```

Usando el paquete `dplyr` podría ser asi,

```
library(dplyr)

df%>%
    rowwise()%>%
    summarise(var1=sum(c(var1,var1.x,var1.y),
        na.rm=T))
```

Answer (score 0):

No especificas los casos de excepción en lo que reglamentas que sucede si existen 2 valores en la misma fila o si no existe ninguno ?

¿Debería quedar NA o tomar algún valor especifico (como 0)?

Suponiendo que en el primer caso toma el primer valor encontrado y el segundo se deja NA, entonces:

```
for (i in 1:nrow(df)) {
 for (j in 1:ncol(df)) {
  if(!is.nan(df[i][j])) {
   df[i][1] <- df[i][j]
   break
  }
 }
}
```

¡Exitos!

Answer (score 0):

Con R base puedes hacer algo muy simple:

```
var1 <- apply(df, 1, max, na.rm = TRUE)
var1

[1] 60  1  7 66 10
```

`apply` es una forma funcional de hacer un ciclo, en este caso se aplica por fila la función `max()` que tiene dos ventajas, si hubiera más de una columna con valor, siempre obtendremos un solo valor, y al mismo tiempo con `na.rm = TRUE` ignoramos los valores `NA`